# how to package python+django+excel project to windows exe file

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

I have written a project using python + django. and the data it needs is stored in excel not in the database. How can I package this project to .exe file so that it can run in the windows without all the python or django environment.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help.

It is really important to me. Any documentations or forums would be a great help. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

[Django To Exe – Distribute your django project as a portable Windows exe application](https://algotronics.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/dj2exe/)